# How to filter an object where one of the fields equals value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with objects

```
[
  {
    id: "id-1",
    p1: {
          id: "123",
        },
    p2: {
           id: "345",
        },
    p3: {
           id: "abc",
        }
  },
  {
    id: "id-2",
    p1: {
          id: "def",
        },
    p2: {
          id: "ghi",
        },
    p3: {
          id: "678",
        }
  },
  {
    id: "id-3",
    p1: {
          id: "zxy",
        },
    p2: {
          id: "912",
        },
    p3: {
          id: "4lk",
        }
  }
]
```

My end goal is to get the id for any object where one of the fields (p-1 or p-2 or p-3) is equal to a value given that any value stored in one of the "p"s is a unique id.

```
  function findId(value: string): id: string => { ??? }

  findId("ghi") = "id-2"
  findId("912") = "id-3"
```

Comment: The second part of your question is very confusing. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: Are you sure this is Java and not JavaScript?

Comment: It is javascript, my mistake sorry

Comment: Javascript has a built in filter method / function.

Comment: right so array.filter(item => item.p1 === value || item.p2 === value || item.p3 === value) ?

Comment: array.filter(item.p1.id === value || item.p2.id === value || item.p3.id === value)[0].id *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of the function 'find' and 'some' can be used here.

```js
let data = [
  {
    id: "id-1",
    p1: {
          id: "123",
        },
    p2: {
           id: "345",
        },
    p3: {
           id: "abc",
        }
  },
  {
    id: "id-2",
    p1: {
          id: "def",
        },
    p2: {
          id: "ghi",
        },
    p3: {
          id: "678",
        }
  },
  {
    id: "id-3",
    p1: {
          id: "zxy",
        },
    p2: {
          id: "912",
        },
    p3: {
          id: "4lk",
        }
  }
]

console.log(findId("912"))
console.log(findId("ghi"))
console.log(findId("notexisiting"))

function findId(id) {
  let matches = data.find(d => Object.values(d).some( field => field.id === id))
  
  if (matches) {
    return matches.id
   }
  
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: If you're just taking the first item from a `filter` then you may as well use `find`

Comment: You are right, I made an edit.

Comment: Thanks that did work, forgot to mention I was using typescript so I had to do 

 let matches = data.find(d => Object.values(d).some( field => typeof field !== "string" && item?.id))